# Creating object name with dash

Tags: php, object

I am trying to run a mysqli query to retrieve a single result, but it requires me to create an object that contains a dash in the name, so it won't work.

```
$style_name = $db2->query("SELECT ModelDesc-ENU FROM tlkpModel WHERE ModelID = '$style' LIMIT 1")->fetch_object()->ModelDesc-ENU;
```

Notice the part `fetch_object()->ModelDesc-ENU;`- It's an invalid object name. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the property in curly braces and quotes:

```
fetch_object()->{'ModelDesc-ENU'};
```

Although I suspect you also need to wrap the column name in ticks, too, as the dash is not a valid identifier characters and actually means you are subtracting ENU from ModelDesc.

```
$style_name = $db2->query("SELECT `ModelDesc-ENU` FROM tlkpModel WHERE ModelID = '$style' LIMIT 1")->fetch_object()->{'ModelDesc-ENU'};
```